# Samesite cookie but allow specific domain

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, setcookie, samesite, cross-site

I would like to secure my cookies using **SameSite=strict**. But is there a way to allow it to be accessed by few domains alone?

Comment: Starting a bounty - is it possible to restrict SameSite to a specific list of domains? If not, is this because the standard or browsers do not support it yet or because it doesn't make sense?

Comment: I want this, but I don't think it can be done ☹️

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the upcoming [First Party Sets](https://github.com/WICG/first-party-sets/) proposal from Google. This allows certain domains to be treated as if requests between them were same-site.

Note, however, that this is still in an early stage, is for now Google-specific and requires you to register the domains in a public repository.

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting `strict` referral domains would be a fantastic enhancement to cookie mgmt, but AFAIK this doesn't exist.

I am evaluating my own solution to set cookies to `LAX` and then implementing my own whitelist that permits specific referrers, if the referring/redirecting website is not on the whitelist to then delete all cookies and force user to the login page.  This would momentarily list/present existing cookies, which could be captured, but would be useless because the page(s) that were redirected to would immediately delete the cookies because the referrer wasn't whitelisted.